# Writing code for deleting calendar item created by sheets data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've written a content management system using Google Sheets that writes assignments to a Google Calendar. The trigger is set up to run manually because any of the Google triggers repopulates the calendar items anytime something changes in the range (I couldn't find a way around it). So, each item is given a unique ID.

This works well, and although you have to run the script again if something changes, the menu is built into the UI. So, it's not to bad. You'll see I also built a UI menu item for deleting the event. I also want to run this manually. There are two sheets in this CMS: One is ongoing projects, which is where this populates. The other is called Completed Projects.

It has all the same data, but when the project is completed, I have a second script that moves it to Completed Projects sheet when they are done (this is based upon a string, and I believe the target is set to onEdit, but it works). Ideally, I would like to have the calendar item be deleted either by running the script using the UI menu (manual trigger, and frankly what I would prefer) or when it moves to the Completed Projects sheet. And this is where I'm running into problems.

I cannot get the logic to work to find the identifier. I was thinking that the way to do this would be to have it look look at the unique ID in the completed folder (it moves with it when the item is completed), and then manually run the deletion from the UI menu. If it finds that ID, then it should remove the calendar item. That script appears in row 7 (column H) in both sheets.

I've tried to make it find the data on that sheet and in that row, and then use the deleteEvent class to call that value and have it delete the event when I trigger the script. The script doesn't generate an error, but it also doesn't delete the calendar item. Here's the code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Calendar Actions')
      .addItem('Export Assignments', 'exportEvents')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Delete Assignments', 'deleteEvents')
      .addToUi();
};


function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "Calendar ID";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[4]);
    var title = row[0];
    var tstart = new Date(row[4]);
    var assignee = row [2]
   var tstop = new Date(row[5]);
   var id = row[7];             
   
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      
    }
    if (!event) {
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:assignee}).getId();
      row[7] = newEvent;
      
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
      event.setDescription(assignee);
           
      
      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
      event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
    }
    debugger;
  }
 
  range.setValues(data);
}

function deleteEvents() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "Calendar ID";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue;
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[4]);
    var title = row[0];
    var tstart = new Date(row[4]);
    var assignee = row [2]
   var tstop = new Date(row[5]);
   var id = row[7];             
   
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
  
    if (!event) {
  var oldEvent = cal.deleteEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:assignee}).getId();
      row[7] = oldEvent;
    }
  }}
```

I think I am missing something - how can I delete the item?

Comment: The [Class Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) does not have a deleteEvent() method. The [Class CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event) has a deleteEvent method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteEvents() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows=1;
  var range=sheet.getRange(headerRows + 1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data=range.getValues();
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar ID");
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][7]) {
       cal.getEventById(data[i][7]).deleteEvent(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works very well, but it introduces a new problem. Because the script always looks for the event ID, it fails if the ID is no longer associated with the event. So, it won't delete any other events that have been completed (it just gives an error that the calendar items is no longer valid. What do I have to tell the code that if the value is false, it ignores it and goes onto the next item?